# Sort a map on the basis of first value of pair

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, key-value

Suppose I have to describe my map as:

```
map<int, pair<long, int>> mp;
```

Now I insert elements as:

```
int y; long x;
pair<long, int> p;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
    cin >> x >> y;
    p.first = x;
    p.second = y;
    mp.insert({i, p});   // What is wrong here syntax wise?
}
```

Further, I want to sort it on the basis of first value of the pair.

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with that last line? Can you change the example to a [mre] with input, actual output, and expected/wanted output?

Comment: It looks ok to me too. You could replace the `insert` with `mp.emplace(i,p);` though.

Comment: not tested, but I would bet that `mp.insert(i, p);` works

Comment: @GianPaolo No, it won't, but `mp.emplace(i,p);` will.

Comment: `std::map` is always sorted by key, you can't sort by value

Comment: std::map is a template. Its third parameter is a comparator function, which allows you to change the way the map is sorted. Which is where Alan Birtles' answer comes in - the comparator is called with the inserted elements' keys. So you can change the map to sort in descending key order, but you can't have it sorted by the mapped type (the pair's first member, in your case).

Comment: If you know amount elements beforehand, you can use two vectors instead of maps. One vector replaces the map, as you use index anyway; vector provides O(n)=1 complexity on elements access. The second array you can use to store values (without keys) and use `std::sort` to sort by first value.

Comment: there is no overload of [map::insert](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) taking a key and a value as parameter. , so the error you are getting

Comment: But why does mp.insert({i,p}); work here because i thought i is a key and p(pair) is a value. But that's okay with if it would have been two integer values i and j the above syntax would have worked, why is there a change like that i am a bit curious to know??

Comment: because it is using the overload taking a `value_pair` (1 in the link above), where value_pair is defined, for your case, as `pair<const int, long>`. compiler is generating a temporary pair<const int, long> with the code `{i,p}`, it figures out that it can create the value_pair from that initialization list (not sure it's actually an initialization list, but that's not the point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a little trick here.

Map in `c++` automatically sorts everything by key, so you can do following =>

```
map <long, (set,vector) < int > > mp; //Create this kind of map
//it will sort elements by first value and depending on your needs, select vector or set
//if you need to sort elements by second value use set
//if you do not care about it use vector

long x;
int y;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   cin >> x >> y;
   if (mp.find(x) != mp.end()) // if element exist
      {
         mp[x].push_back(y); // add it to vector
      }
      else
      {
         mp[x] = vector < int > (); // if not create new vector
         mp[x].push_back(y); // and then push new element
      }
}
```

Comment: In map key is any int value but its value i need to store as x,y so i chose pair now i am doubtful how to sort it on the basis of first value of pair i.e. x here. our map is basically like map<key,pair<x,y>>

Comment: Thankful for the response but would be grateful if you could reply to query in above comment

Comment: You still can do this way, with the same principle =>

map <long, vector < pair < long, int > > > mp;
//this case you will still get sorted map, and get pair as you need

Comment: Or set if you one more time need to elements to be sorted also by second element

Comment: yes you are correct but in your free time i would request you to give me just a sort function because i had tried but could not go with it. Would be grateful if you could help. Anyways that's superb way to get through. Just help me sort too. Thank you

Comment: it is impossible in c/c++. You can try another languages for example python

Comment: @YUV put this one as resolved since you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::map` in indexed and ordered by its key. Full stop.

I can only imagine 2 possible ways to have it *sorted* according to its values:

- reverse the struct to have the element giving the order as the key (this is @Suspicio's answer)
- use what is called a *secondary* index in database world, that is an auxialiary *thing* that will be sorted according to your requirements and point to the real data.

Here, I would use either a vector of integers (the keys to your actual map) if you can accept to sort it once before using it (said differently if you map does not change once populated) or a `std::multimap` if you want to be able to easily add (or remove) items.

```
multimap<long, int> indices;
for (auto elt : mp) {
    indices.insert({ elt.second.first, elt.first });
}
```

You can now the process your *sorted* map:

```
for (auto index : indices) {
    auto elt = mp.find(index.second); // *elt will give the elements in order
    ...
}
```

You just have to update the `indices` multimap whenever you add or remove elements to your original `mp` map.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have to learn more in order to understand this though